# Expanding pandas string column of floats memory-efficiently

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame such as this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Col1Val', 'Col2Val', '[3, 31.1, -341.4, 54.13]']],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2','values'])
```

The only differences are I have a few million rows and column `values` is a string of exactly 200 floats in each row, instead of 4 in my example.

The csv file containing this data is ~5 GB. However, this reduces when I load into pandas after converting the first 2 string columns into categories. Hence I am able to perform most manipulations (filtering, slicing, indexing) with no performance issues.

I need to expand the `values` column of strings into separate columns of floats. So there will be 200 columns each containing a float. I made an attempt at performing this, but I consistently run out of memory. Theoretically, I think this should be possible line by line in a memory efficient way, since columns of floats should take less memory than many numbers in a string. What's a good algorithm for this?

My existing code is below for splitting `values` column.

```
df['values'] = df['values'].str.replace('[','').str.replace(']','')

# code runs out of memory in next line!
df_values = pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in df['values'].values.tolist()])

df_values[df_values.columns] = df_values[df_values.columns].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df_values[df_values.columns] = df_values[df_values.columns].fillna(0.0)

df= df.drop('values', 1).join(df_values)
```

Expected result for my sample, which above code generates correctly for small number of rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Col1Val', 'Col2Val', 3.0, 31.1, -341.4, 54.13]],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2', 0, 1, 2, 3])
```

To labour my reasoning for why I'm hoping (wishing!) for a "memory decreasing" solution, `floats` should normally take less space than `string`:

```
from sys import getsizeof

getsizeof('334.34')      #55
getsizeof(334.34)        #24
getsizeof('-452.35614')  #59
getsizeof(-452.35614)    #24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For smaller datasets: (see below if this method fails due to memory issue.)

You can also try this.

```
df['values'].str[1:-1].str.split(",", expand=True).astype(float)
```

The first `str[1:-1]` operation removes the brackets.

`str.split` will split the rest of the values by `,` and expand it into a dataframe (with the `expand=True`)

```
    0       1       2       3
0   3.0     31.1    -341.4  54.13
```

You can also split the string by `[ , ]`

```
df['values'].str.split(r"[\[,\]]", expand=True).astype(float)
```

but this will results in two extra columns

```
    0   1   2       3       4       5
0       3   31.1    -341.4  54.13
```

#### Edit: (For large dataset.)

One might try to fix it from the reading data part.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
```

Here, we change the quote char to `"` such that the original quote char `'` will be ignored. We then just split by `,`. Then, we will need to do some data preprocessing to fix the misparsed part.

Given my `test.csv` being

```
 c1,c2,v1,v2,v3,v4
'Col1Val', 'Col2Val', '[3, 31.1, -341.4, 54.13]'
'Col1Val', 'Col2Val', '[3, 31.1, -341.4, 54.13]'
'Col1Val', 'Col2Val', '[3, 31.1, -341.4, 54.13]'
```

The result of the `read_csv` is

```
    c1          c2          v1      v2      v3      v4
0   'Col1Val'   'Col2Val'   '[3     31.1    -341.4  54.13]'
1   'Col1Val'   'Col2Val'   '[3     31.1    -341.4  54.13]'
2   'Col1Val'   'Col2Val'   '[3     31.1    -341.4  54.13]'
```

Now, we can use some [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) methods to fix each column. **Note**: if there is comma in `c1`/`c2`, the results would be wrong.

Comment: I actually tried `str.split(',', expand=True)`, it's still a "memory increasing" solution which blow up for my data. Am I thinking incorrectly that the size should reduce? Since "[334.34, 32144.32, 652.324]" should be more costly than [334.34, 32144.32, 652.324], right?

Comment: @jp_data_analysis I am not sure about your last observation, though. Yet too bad that it does not help.

Comment: appreciate your effort. Have upvoted as it is likely no worse than COLDSPEED's solutions. I've also added some reasoning to my question.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis another possibility is that you pass in a different set of delimiters while using `read_csv`? So that it split by `[ , ]` at the first place?

Comment: @jp_data_analysis check out my update :P Best of luck.

Comment: with some minor modifications your idea of re-wiring `pd.read_csv` worked perfectly. thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**
Parse your string column with `ast.literal_eval`/`pd.eval` (it's the easiest first step).

```
import ast
df['values'] = df['values'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Next, flatten the last column and `concat`enate with the remaining `n - 1` columns.

```
i = df.iloc[:, :-1]
j = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:, -1].tolist())

pd.concat([i, j], 1)

     col1     col2  0     1      2      3
0  Col1Val  Col2Val  3  31.1 -341.4  54.13
```

Here's an improved version for efficiency. Use `del` for inplace deletion of columns, and cut out all the slicing operations (they create copies, and are wasteful).

```
j = pd.DataFrame(df['values'].tolist())
del df['values']

pd.concat([df, j], 1)

      col1     col2  0     1      2      3
0  Col1Val  Col2Val  3  31.1 -341.4  54.13
```

---

**Option 2**
`str.extractall` (can't guarantee performance).

```
df = df.set_index(['col1', 'col2'])['values']\
       .str.extractall('(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)')\
       .unstack()

df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
df.reset_index()

match     col1     col2  0     1      2      3
0      Col1Val  Col2Val  3  31.1  341.4  54.13
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED, thanks I'll give this a go. Certainly looks more efficient, depending on performance of `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis Added option 2, for your perusal. I'd be willing to bet, though, the first is faster.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis Okay, I see your data is huge, so I added a much more performant version of option 1.

Comment: @COLDSPEED, with all these methods (and indeed jezrael's) I see memory increasing and eventually yielding MemoryError. Is that expected since none of these operations are in place? The end product should take less memory, so I was hoping there was a clever way to have a "memory decreasing" solution.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis If even these methods are erroring out, then it might be time to look at something else that can handle this... possibly `dask` dataframes.

Comment: Yep, I think `dask.dataframe` the way forward. Memory decreasing solution still a dream! Appreciate your help, though, this deserves an up-vote. But I will keep the question open in case someone thinks of `pandas` solution.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis Yeah. Let's see if someone else can come up with something. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column with `apply` for convert to `list`s and `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df1 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('values').apply(pd.io.json.loads).values.tolist()))
print (df1)

      col1     col2  0     1      2      3
0  Col1Val  Col2Val  3  31.1 -341.4  54.13

print (df1.dtypes)
col1     object
col2     object
0         int64
1       float64
2       float64
3       float64
dtype: object
```